# Can a Docker container uses the full CPU power and memory of the host OS?

Tags: virtualization, lamp, lxc, docker, containers

I am new to Docker, but I have experience of using VM and hypervisor. Referring to Docker introduction and [this image](http://pointful.github.io/docker-intro/docker-img/containers-vs-vms.png), Docker containers are isolated but share the same host OS.

If we deploy only 1 Docker container (e.g. LAMP app) in a host OS, can the Docker container uses the full CPU power and memory of the host OS?

Is there any performance difference between a LAMP app running in a Docker container and a LAMP app running in the host OS directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: There is a difference but generally so small that it's not worth worrying about.

For the most part, containers can use the full CPU and RAM of the host system. There is a little bit of CPU overhead to actually run a container but it's small enough that it's generally considered to be zero. RAM usage is in the same boat. The docker server does require a certain amount of CPU and RAM. Both are pretty small when compared to running the app in a VM.